# setOnClickListener Adapter em um objeto da linha de uma ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

Meu app possui uma ListView, na qual recebe informações de um Json (URL), e cada linha possui uma ImageView que ao clicar, as informações da linha serão adicionadas como "Favorito".

Para isso, criei duas imagens (iconfav_off e iconfav_on),

Então criei o layout recebendo o iconfav_off como inicial.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/iconfav_off"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/starFav"
    android:tag="off"/>
```

Ao clicar nesse objeto específico (não na linha da ListView), preciso que usa seja trocada para "iconfav_on".

Para isso, criei um setOnClickListener para o objeto, dentro do meu Adapter

```
    ImageView Fav = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.starFav);
    Fav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            FavStatus = String.valueOf(view.getTag());
            if(FavStatus.equals("off")){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ADICIONADO AOS FAVORITOS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.iconfav_on);
                view.setTag("on");
            }
            if(FavStatus.equals("on")){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "REMOVIDO DOS FAVORITOS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.iconfav_off);
                view.setTag("off");
            }

        }
    });
```

Ele verifica a tag (se off ou on) e efetua a troca.

Porém **MINHA DIFICULDADE** está sendo que a troca está acontecendo em várias linhas, quando deveria ser acontecer somente no objeto da linha clicada.

Já tentei da seguinte forma e o resultado foi o mesmo

```
    ImageView Fav = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.starFav);
    Fav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            ImageView FavStatus = (ImageView) ((View) view.getParent()).findViewById(R.id.starFav);
            FavStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.iconfav_on);
        }
    });
```

Também ajustei o código para pegar o "position" da linha clicada, mas não sei como setar a imagem do objeto dessa posição, e nesse caso, eu perco a "Tag" de controle de "off" ou "on".

```
    ImageView Fav = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.starFav);
    Fav.setTag(position);
    Fav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            View parentRow = (View) view.getParent();
            ListView listView = (ListView) parentRow.getParent();
            final int position = listView.getPositionForView(parentRow);

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "botão da posição: " + view.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            ?????

        }
    });
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar, de forma antecipada já agradeço

**UPDATE**

Segue abaixo o Adapter completo

```
class AgendaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Agenda> {

AgendaAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Agenda> agenda) {
    super(context, 0, agenda);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    final Agenda agenda = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.agenda_linha, parent, false);
    }

    TextView tvTitulo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.clubeAgendaTitulo);
    TextView tvData = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.clubeAgendaData);
    TextView tvHora = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.clubeAgendaHora);

    assert agenda != null;

    tvTitulo.setText(agenda.Nome);
    tvData.setText(agenda.Data);
    tvHora.setText(agenda.Hora);


/***********************************************/
/******TRECHOS DAS TENTATIVAS ANTERIORES *******/
/***********************************************/

    return convertView;
}
```

---

### **RESOLVIDO EM RESPOSTA**

Comment: Acredito que precisaríamos ver o código do `Adapter`. Não recomendo fazer alterações somente na `View`, porque o `ListView` utiliza um padrão de reciclagem de `Views`, se você não tratar o atributo `FavStatus` do modelo no seu `Adapter, `não vai ter muita solução. Minha recomendação é que parta para o `RecyclerView`, pois não vai precisar tratar alteração de `View` fora do `Adapter`.

Comment: @Wakim , coloquei um UPDATE do código do Adapter. Como eu usaria o RecyclerView no meu código? É realmente o caso de usar o RecyclerView ? Qual a utilidade dessa função ?

Comment: Então, como seu layout é bem simples, convém de manter usando o ListView. Mas pra layouts mais complexos é recomendado fazer uso dele ao invés do ListView. Voltando ao problema, você precisa atualizar a sua ImageView também dentro do getView do seu Adapter, baseado no item Agenda. Pra isso precisa atualizar item Agenda ao invés de adicionar uma Tag na View. Caso não consiga, posso fazer uma resposta amanhã cedo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

para quem teve a mesma dúvida que eu, assim como me ajudaram, vou deixar abaixo o código na qual resolveu meu problema, para que possa ajudar a outros.

Consegui resolver, a partir da orientação do @Wakim, nos comentários:

> ... você precisa atualizar a sua ImageView também dentro do getView do seu Adapter, baseado no item Agenda. Pra isso precisa atualizar item Agenda ao invés de adicionar uma Tag na View.

Como sou iniciante, não sei se o código está escrito de maneira apropriada, mas funcionou.

Diante da pergunta, o trecho de código abaixo, entra no espaço comentado "TRECHOS DAS TENTATIVAS ANTERIORES", do Adapter.

```
    ImageView Fav = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.starFav);
    Fav.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.iconfav_off);
    if(agenda.Fav.equals("on")){ Fav.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.iconfav_on); }

    Fav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String FavSatus = agenda.Fav;
            if(FavSatus.equals("off")){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ADICIONADO AOS FAVORITOS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.iconfav_on);
                agenda.Fav = "on";
            }
            if(FavSatus.equals("on")){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "REMOVIDO DOS FAVORITOS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.iconfav_off);
                agenda.Fav = "off";
            }
        }
    });
```

Ao clicar no botão de Favorito, eu altero a imagem do objeto, e defino o valor de agenda.Fav.

Para corrigir o problema de que o objeto estava sendo alterado nas demais linhas, o que fiz foi setar o "off" como padrão, para todos os itens da lista, e alterar para "on" se o meu item Agenda.Fav fosse "on";

```
Fav.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.iconfav_off);
if(agenda.Fav.equals("on")){ Fav.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.iconfav_on); }
```

Agora o valor padrão e a verificação de cada item, acontecerá sempre que exibir/reexibir o item ao realizar um scroll na ListView.

Depois de ajustado e explicado, pode parecer obvio o código, mas para quem está iniciando no Java/Android (como eu estou), pode ser prejuízo de algumas horas de trabalho.

Agradeço novamente ao @Wakim pela orientação.